# Spring Security: Simple Encryption / decryption not working: InvalidKeyException

Tags: java, spring-boot, encryption, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to write a very simple program to encrypt and decrypt a string:

```
    String password = "kdfljxcasd";
    String encodeThat = "Hello World + some special chars!^^-";
    String salt = KeyGenerators.string().generateKey();
    BytesEncryptor encryptor = Encryptors.standard(password, salt);

    // breakpoint steping doesn't reach that point - it gets stuck here for some reason... 
    byte[] encrypted = encryptor.encrypt(encodeThat.getBytes());
    byte[] decrypted = encryptor.decrypt(encrypted);

    System.out.println("Before encryption: " + encodeThat);     
    System.out.println("Encrypted: " + encrypted.toString());       
    System.out.println("After encryption: " + decrypted.toString());
```

But for some reason I never get an encrypted value. When I call `enryptor.encrypt()` it never reaches that point.

I'm getting the following exception:

```
'Unable to initialize due to invalid secret key' java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to initialize due to invalid secret key
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after hours of searching I finally found the solution:

Appearently I didn't have the correct policies for unlimited Strength installed.

That's the way I solved it:

1. Download the policies from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html
2. Unpack that and put **local_policy.jar** and **US_export_policy.jar** into ${jdk -path}/jre/lib/security and override the existing files. (ATTENTION: Don't put it in the JRE folder. You have to put it into jdk/jre/... ... - that took me hours :) )
3. Restart the server and it works!

Hope that helped :)

Comment: is there a way to do it without adding external jars?

Comment: Not that I know, sorry. But would you need a solution without external jars?

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 8u151 you can resolve this with a property:

`Security.setProperty("crypto.policy", "unlimited");`

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade to newer java 8 JDK version.

For me I tried 2 versions:

- 1.8.131 - failed
- 1.8.201 - success

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this problem and fixed it by switching from `JDK 1.8` to `Adopt Open JDK 8`